# Setting Program Description and Company Name with Win32 API

Tags: c++, c, winapi

In the Task Manager there is a column that shows a description of the program running. Looking at Process Explorer there is also a field for the Company Name of the company that produced the program.

How can I programatically set these fields using C/C++, and specifically not .NET, so that my program can show something useful in them?

Comment: These are properties of the compiled program and not specified at runtime. Ben gives you an answer on how to set them at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean you want these set while building your program, or you want to write a program that changes these properties of an arbitrary binary file?

In the first case, [you pass a `VERSIONINFO` resource to the resource compiler to be embedded into your binary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058.aspx).

In the second case, you need to use [the Resource Editor APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648030.aspx) (and also understand the internal format of `VERSIONINFO` resources.  Or use the Resource Compiler to make a new `VERSIONINFO`` resource and use the Resource APIs to swap it.)

Comment: The first link is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!